# Perl tk doesn't find the display

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

:)

I've just started to use Perl Tk on Ubuntu 12.04. I want to run a simple test code, but I get the following error:

```
couldn't connect to display ":0" at /usr/lib/perl5/Tk/MainWindow.pm line 55.
Tk::MainWindow->new() at tk_proba.pl line 5.
```

The code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use Tk;

$mw=Tk::MainWindow->new();
Tk::MainLoop();
```

I don't really find a solution which works well.

Comment: Type `echo $DISPLAY` - it should contain something like `:0.0`

Comment: Yes, I was log in as root, that was the problem! :) Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a different user on your command line as you are logged into on your X server? i.e. did you log in as `erbal` but you `su`d to `root` before running your program?

This is a common problem that can affect an X user - and can be baffling because it just worked before! The problem relates to the display environment variables going missing. Some of the variables that are needed:

- `$DISPLAY`
- [`$XAUTHORITY`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization)